# Pattern and Matcher in Java in CDATA tag

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to replace `&amp;` with `&` in my xml file.

Here is my code :

```
//On match sur tous les <!CDATA[ ... ]>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!\\[CDATA\\[((&amp;)|[^\\]]|\\][^\\]]|\\]\\][^>])*\\]\\]>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(l_retour.toString());

String temp2 ="";
temp2 = l_retour.toString();
while(m.find()){
        //Si il y a un '&amp;'  
        if(m.group(2) != null){
                //On remaplace les &amp; remplacés précédement par un '&' simple car on se trouve dans une balise <!CDATA[]>
                temp2 = temp2.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(m.group()),m.group().replaceAll("&amp;", "&"));
        }
}
```

There are an error in execution :

```
04 26 17:02:48,733 FATAL ExporteXml: Illegal group reference 
04 26 17:02:48,733 FATAL ExporteXml: java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:808) 
04 26 17:02:48,733 FATAL ExporteXml: java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:955) 
04 26 17:02:48,733 FATAL ExporteXml: java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2119)
```

I suppose it's my regex but y didn't find solution.. 
Thanks by advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that `l_retour` is a String variable containing the whole XML file:

`l_retour = l_retour.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");` should be enough for you.

Comment: Thant you for your answer. I can't do this because i just want to replace in CDATA tag. `<![CDATA[here is my text to replace]]>`

Comment: @Vasan funnily though, `replace()` internally uses `replaceAll()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at your stacktrace you'll note that it's in `replaceFirst(...)`. Thus I assume that your problem is what you pass to `temp2.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(m.group()),m.group().replaceAll("&amp;", "&"));` - most probably it's the second parameter that is interpreted in regex terms (to allow for group references such as `$1`).

However, you don't need to do that, just replace `&amp;` inside the match:

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while( m.find() ) {
  String replacement = m.group();
  if(m.group(2) != null){
    replacement = replacement.replace( "&amp;", "&" );
  }
  m.appendReplacement( result, replacement );
}
m.appendTail( result );
```

You might not even need to check for `&amp;` in your expression, just get all CDATAs and replace any `&amp;`. If none is present nothing will be replaced.

However, I'll issue a warning: **applying regular expressions to irregular languages such as XML is a receipe for disaster!** Unless you know what your CDATA can contain it's likely you won't find a pattern that matches everything (e.g. I know of some people who put XML into CDATA ... ouch). When dealing with XML you're normally better off using a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

I listen to you and i simply do this :

```
//On match sur tous les <!CDATA[ ... ]>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!\\[CDATA\\[.+\\]\\]>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(l_retour.toString());              
String result = l_retour.toString();
String replacement = "", replacementTmp = "";
while(m.find()){
    replacementTmp = m.group();
    //On remaplace les &amp; remplacés précédement par un '&' simple car on se trouve dans une balise <!CDATA[]>
    replacement = replacementTmp.replace("&amp;", "&");
    int indexBegin = result.indexOf(replacementTmp);
    int indexEnd = result.length() - 1;
    result = result.substring(0, indexBegin) + replacement + result.substring(indexBegin + replacementTmp.length(), indexEnd);
}
```

Thanks